# String to int cpp

Tags: c++, string

Can someone please explain me how this code works(the part inside for loop)? Thanks.

The question is: Given an n-digit large number in form of string, check whether it is divisible by 7 or not. Print 1 if divisible by 7, otherwise 0.

Example 1:

Input: num = "8955795758"
Output: 1
Explanation: 8955795758 is divisible by 7.

Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Solution{
    public:
    
    int isdivisible7(string num){
        int carry = 0;
        
        for(auto x: num)
        {
            int digit = x - '0';
            
            carry = carry * 10 + digit;
            
            carry = carry % 7;
        }
        return carry == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
};

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        Solution ob;
        cout << ob.isdivisible7(s) << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: One could make the case that [the code does not work at all](https://godbolt.org/z/rds6zjW4x).

Comment: But seriously, you're better off with a question that describes how you think it works and then asking if you are right. If you're right, cool. That was easy. If you aren't, answers can focus in on where your logic goes wrong.

Comment: Is the mathematics behind this a problem? Or is it the C++ part? How would you program it?

Answer (score 1):

```
int digit = x - '0';
```

This line translates digit symbol into int type digit. In other words, we don't try to translate full string into int at once, but taking one digit translating it from the symbol type to int type. For example, if string is '57892' at the second iteration `x` would be equal "7" and `digit` would be equal 7

```
carry = carry * 10 + digit;
```

The line adds the digit to the part of number which have been found from previous digits

```
carry = carry % 7;
```

The line founds the remainder of the division for the part which is already obtained.

#### For example:

You have received number 57325. It will take firstly 5 and at a the and of the first iteration of the loop `carry` would be equal 5. At the next iteration it will change `carry` to 57 and after finding a remainder it will be equal to 1. It means that 57325 and 1325 are or either both divisible by 7 or either both not, so we could proceed with the smaller one. At the next iteration carry after second line will be equal to 13 and after taking remainder it would be equal to 6. So as it has been before, it means that 1325 and 625 are or either both divisible by 7 or either both not, so we could proceed with the smaller one. Continuing the process function finds if number is divisible.

It is important to take remainder because string could be very big and int without taking remainder would not have enough space to keep it.